# JSLint fails file due to undefined variable

Tags: javascript, enums, jslint

I have just started putting JSLint into my build pipeline and it has been great. Although it has pointed out something in most of my files that is not an error as such, although it will see it as one. I have changed my constructor to now take an instance of this object so the tests pass, however I am not sure if I really should, as in all other major languages I would not need to do this.

I will have to add some more context to this, for it to make any sense so here goes.

I have the closest thing I can get to an Enum in javascript which is basically a globally scoped JSON style variable with a load of constants, it is used to describe event types so rather than every class that wants to raise/listen to events having to put hard coded strings, it can just use a constant from this *enum* variable. As I just mentioned I have these classes that make use of this *static enum*, but they just make use of the global version of this variable, not a local instance passed through the constructor, and this is where my problems begin, as in the actual app I know for a fact that the enum file will included which will make it globally accessible. However JSLint has no context of this, so it only sees an individual file without worrying about external dependencies, as it deems these to be bad, which in any other language would be true, but in JS you cannot achieve the same thing without having global variables (to my knowledge).

As I said originally, I have now added this enum to the constructor to let JSLint pass the files, however it just feels a bit wrong passing it in, but maybe this is because I am thinking about it as a regular developer and not a javascript developer...

Now should I stick to this, and pass it through the constructor, and just mock it in my tests, or should I take the approach that it *should* always be there?

I am sure this will be down to peoples personal opinions, but it would be nice to know if I am being an idiot and should just keep each file as its own silo, or if there is a way for me to have my cake and eat it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that JSLint supports a comment to tell it of global variables:

```
/*globals myGlobal*/
```

I have decided to just use my enum as a global and get on with the more important things.

Answer (score 0):

JavascriptLint greatly improves on JSLint in this respect, as it allows you to define inter-file dependencies:

> If a script references a variable, function, or object from another script, you will need to add a **/*jsl:import PathToOtherScript*/** comment in your script. This tells JavaScript Lint to check for items declared in the other script. Relative paths are resolved based on the path of the current script.

See: http://javascriptlint.com/docs/index.htm

Comment: I long for the day when we can use Microsoft-style 'reference' tags. E.g.: /// <reference path="xxx" />. This would allow me to have intelli-sense and keep JSLint happy at the same time.